# Prove $\frac{3}{2} +\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b} \leqq \frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c} +\frac{c}{a}$

Tags: inequality, symmetric-polynomials, sum-of-squares-method, uvw

For $a,\,b,\,c>0$. Prove: $$\frac{3}{2} +\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b} \leqq \frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c} +\frac{c}{a}$$
My work:
After a lot of caculates, I found:

$\text{RHS-LHS}=$
[image]

However, it's hard to find in a competition.

So I wanna to find a simple way for it without Buffalo Way! Thanks a lot!

Comment: [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7B3%7D%7B2%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Ba%7D%7Bb%2Bc%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Bb%7D%7Bc%2Ba%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Bc%7D%7Ba%2Bb%7D%5Cle%5Cfrac%7Ba%7D%7Bb%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Bb%7D%7Bc%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Bc%7D%7Ba%7D%24) shows a few results.

Comment: @tthnew I have found a very nice proof of your problem.

Comment: Solutions on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h262433p1425935, https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h598876p3554330.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg what is your proof?

Comment: @tthnew I posted.

Comment: @Saad  In your link, Jun 4, 2008, can_hang2007 gave a elegant proof: $\frac{3}{2} \le \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{ac}{b(b+c)} = \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{(ac)^2}{abc(b+c)}$, then apply CS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By C-S $$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a}{b}-\frac{a}{b+c}\right)=\sum_{cyc}\frac{ac}{b(b+c)}=\frac{1}{abc}\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2c^2}{b+c}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{(ab+ca+bc)^2}{2abc(a+b+c)}\geq\frac{3}{2}.$$